How to access custom torchserve metrics in kserve
So, I am using torchserve to create a handler and then using the ".mar" file for creating an inference service using kserve on kubeflow.
I am able to see the custom metrics locally at 8082/metrics, but after deploying it, I am not able to see those custom metrics on the same endpoint, I am only able to see 3 metrics which are default I guess (ts_inference_latency_microseconds, ts_inference_requests_total, ts_queue_latency_microseconds). If any one has any idea about this please help me.
Ref - https://github.com/kserve/kserve/blob/master/qpext/README.md#configs
Thank you for your time
